# How to fix leap year logic in age calculator and find the age?

Tags: c++

I have to make a program for age calculation but I want to put leap year logic because if I am 19 years old I have passed through the leaps year during these 19 years of my life.

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int age, months, years, days, minutes, seconds, hours, leapyear, y;
    cout<<"Enter your age in years::";
    cin>>age;

    days=age*365;
    cout<<"Age in days is:"<<days;

    months=age*12;
    cout<<"\nAge in months is:"<<months;

    hours=days*24;
    cout<<"\nAge in hours is:"<<hours;

    minutes=hours*60;
    cout<<"\nAge in minutes is:"<<minutes;

    seconds=minutes*60;
    cout<<"\nAge in seconds is:"<<seconds;


// How to fix leap year logic in this program i tried but failed to do so....

    return 0;
}
```

Current Output:

```
Enter your age in years::19
Age in days::6935
Age in months::228
Age in hours::166440
Age in minutes::9986400
Age in seconds::599184000
```

Comment: For starters you'd have to add some kind of input as to what year they were born so you could check how many leap years had passed since then

Comment: you are right but i want to do i want to do it without entering my date of birth. Please help me

Comment: If you don't want to ask for the birthdate it will be inaccurate, but you should be able to just add (age%4) to days and get your rough numbers

Comment: All respectable members i am confused about to put logic like (age%4). Please tell me how to put Date of Birth logic and how it will work.

Comment: If i succeeded to put Date of Birth logic in my program then how it will identify the leap years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have said you do not want to ask for the birthdate the simplest way would be to change the int type to a double and have your years represented by 365.25 days each year. This way every four years it adds to one full day representing a leap year.

```
   #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double age, months, years, days, minutes, seconds, hours;
    int min, sec;
    cout<<"Enter your age in years::";
    cin>>age;

//Alternate option if you do not want to ask for date
//Add a quarter of a day each year, every four years it will add to 1 day

    days=age*365.25; // Get days from ages
    cout<<"Age in days is:"<<days;

    months=age*12;
    cout<<"\nAge in months is:"<<months;

    hours=days*24;
    cout<<"\nAge in hours is:"<<hours;

    minutes=hours*60;
// to make it an integer and not convert to scientific notation with high numbers
    min = (int)minutes;
    cout<<"\nAge in minutes is:"<<minutes;

    seconds=minutes*60;
    sec = (int)seconds;
    cout<<"\nAge in seconds is:"<<seconds;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Respectable members when i compiled this program it is done successfully but when it runs, it shows some garbage values

Comment: @IjlalHussain Such as?

Comment: Such as Age in minutes is:99324e+006                                                        and Age in seconds:99594e+008

Comment: Before it was putting it to scientific notation for larger numbers. Just added a fix for that if you prefer it to not be in scientific notation.

Comment: @gabbo1092 casting to int will produce incorrect results for people over 68, [std::fixed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) would be better

Comment: It would have been simpler not to change the types of the variables.

Comment: @AlanBirtles true always forget about that. Although it does also add a lot of unnecessary 0s behind the decimal point. I'll leave it as is for now because the scope for age range for this project is unknown and if the OP doesn't mind the decimals they can use that method.

Comment: As the variable _days_ is not initialized, the expression _days+=age*365.25_ would lead to non-deterministic behavior. Suggestion: change the expression to _days=age*365.25_.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to let other people do the heavy lifting and use a library. Howard Hinnant's [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library makes this stuff easier:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "date.h"
#include <chrono>

using namespace date;

int main()
{
    int years = 19;
    auto today = year_month_day{ floor<days>(std::chrono::system_clock::now()) };
    auto birthday = year(static_cast<int>(today.year()) - years) / today.month() / today.day();
    auto age = static_cast< sys_days >( today ) - static_cast< sys_days >( birthday );
    std::cout << "you are " << age.count() << " days old\n";
    std::cout << "you are " << std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::hours >( age ).count() << " hours old\n";
    std::cout << "you are " << std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::minutes >(age).count() << " minutes old\n";
    std::cout << "you are " << std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::seconds >(age).count() << " seconds old\n";
    return 0;
}
```